# How can i use my created reference from custom directive on other element?

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete, angular-directive

I am trying to reproduce the first example on Angular Material's autocompleted component
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I need to have reusable component as they have but I can't find a way how they do that.

So they have a directive called `matAutocomplete` and one custom component `mat-autocomplete`.
First, they create reference on the custom component with `#auto="matAutocomplete"`. Once the reference variable is created they send that reference to the `matAutocomplete` directive with this code on the input `[matAutocomplete]="auto"`.

When I try to reproduce the same thing, I make for example one custom autcomplete directive and one custom autocomplete component.

As you can see they are both empty - so there is nothing in the HTML in the custom-created component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css']
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

**TOOLTIP DIRECTIVE**

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutocompleteCustom]',
  exportAs: 'appAutocompleteCustom'
})
export class AutocompleteCustomDirective {

  @Input() appAutocompleteCustom;

  constructor() { }
}
```

After that in the `app.component.ts` file when i try the same thing like they do

```
<input type="text"
[appAutocompleteCustom]="auto" 
/>
<app-autocomplete #auto="appAutocompleteCustom" ></app-autocomplete>
```

i get error

`There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "appAutocompleteCustom"`.
So to prevent this error to happen i need to add the keyword `appAutocompleteCustom` so the name of the directive on the element where i created the reference.

```
<app-autocomplete #auto="appAutocompleteCustom" appAutocompleteCustom></app-autocomplete>
```

after this the error is gone. My question is how they do this ? How they are not having the error when they are not attaching the directive keyword on their `mat-autocomplete` component

Answer (score 0):

Because they used exportAs when they declare mat-autocomplete component

The code is here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  exportAs: 'matAutocomplete', <-- this line
  inputs: ['disableRipple'],
  providers: [...],
})
export class MatAutocomplete extends _MatAutocompleteBase {
  ...
}
```

By the definition of exportAs, `Defines the name that can be used in the template to assign this directive to a variable.` [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#exportAs).

You also declare exportAs `exportAs: 'appAutocompleteCustom'`. But it's inside `AutocompleteCustomDirective`. That why when you add the directive

```html
<app-autocomplete #auto="appAutocompleteCustom" appAutocompleteCustom></app-autocomplete>
```

the error is gone